# How to make sql table column from jsonb int array

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with jsonb array column like:

```
 name   |  arr
---------------
 n1     [1,2,3]
 n2     [4,5,6]
```

I want to get a table from it like:

```
name   |  element
---------------
  n1        1
  n1        2
  n1        3
  n2        4
  n2        5
  n2        6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements_text`

```
select name,j.el::int as element
   from t cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(arr) as j(el)
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=12200f2dd13f2f7093db5bb75dddab91)

Comment: Or without a join, simply: `SELECT name, jsonb_array_elements_text(arr) AS element FROM t`